# Settings initial values of system properties found in persistent_properties file

Tags: android, android-source, odroid

I am trying to figure out how I can set initial values for properties that are written to file

```
/data/property/persistent_properties
```

when trying to build an android image.

When using `SystemProperties.set()` the property value gets written there fine but I dont want to have to manually set the property every time I flash an image and want to have it built in already.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property you need to the PRODUCT_VENDOR_PROPERTIES or PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES build time variables to the appropriate make file of your product.

For example take a look at `device/generic/goldfish/vendor.mk`

Comment: I thought PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES and PRODUCT_VENDOR_PROPERTIES went into their respective folders ie `/system` and `/vendor` which wouldn't be the `/data/property`

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Do you need to change the property on the fly? If it is constant and does not change I would have used PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES or PRODUCT_VENDOR_PROPERTIES. If you do need it to be changeable, I would have added an init.rc script to set it up.

Comment: Ideally be able to change it on the fly